# Guardar independientemente por cada FECHA

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos,

Estoy haciendo un programa de consultas medicas y necesito hacer lo siguiente pero no encuentro la manera de como hacerlo:

Necesito que cada vez que un paciente venga a mi consulta medica, yo guarde junto con el día que vino la historia medica, para que la proxíma vez que el vuelva a venir yo pueda ver las historias anteriores segun su fecha.

Actualmente solo tengo lo siguiente, pero no se como hacer para hacer una consulta por fecha y poder consultar luego esa fecha para ver que se escribio ese día.

Tal como lo tengo solo puedo modificar el archivo ya creado, pero no se como hacer parar separar por fechas, adjunto fotos de mi base de datos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php  

include('conexion.php');
$boton = $_POST["boton"];
$cedula = $_POST["CED_PAC"];
$nombre = $_POST["NOM_PAC"];
$apellido = $_POST["APE_PAC"];
$edad = $_POST["EDAD_PAC"];
$nhistoria = $_POST["HIS_PAC"];
$direccion = $_POST["DIR_PAC"];
$telefono = $_POST["TEL_PAC"];
$celular = $_POST["CEL_PAC"];
$sexo = $_POST["SEX_PAC"];
$codigo = $_POST["COD_CONSULTA"];
$fecha = $_POST["FECHA"];
$tipconsulta = $_POST["TIPO_CONSULTA"];
$observacion = $_POST["OBSERV"];
$sintomas = $_POST["SINTOMAS"];
$peso = $_POST["PESO_PAC"];
$altura = $_POST["ALT_PAC"];
$operado = $_POST["OPERADO"];
$alergias = $_POST["ALERGIAS"];
$medicamentos = $_POST["MEDI_PAC"];

if ($boton == "Registrar"){
 $sql = "insert into datosmedicos (CED_PAC, ALT_PAC, PESO_PAC, COD_CONSULTA, TIPO_CONSULTA, SINTOMAS, OBSERV, OPERADO, ALERGIAS,MEDI_PAC ) values ('$cedula','$altura', '$peso', '$codigo', '$tipconsulta', '$sintomas', '$observacion', '$operado', '$alergias', '$medicamentos')";

 if (mysql_query($sql)){
  echo "<script>alert('Usuario guardado correctamente')</script>";
  echo "<script> window.location='consulta.php'</script>";
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>alert('El usuario no puede ser registrado, compruebe que todos los campos esten llenos')</script>";
 }
}

if ($boton == "Buscar"){
 $sql = "select * from datosbasicos where CED_PAC = '$cedula'";
 $busqueda =mysql_query($sql);

 if ($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
  $cedula = $registro['CED_PAC'];
  $nhistoria = $registro['HIS_PAC'];
  $sexo = $registro['SEX_PAC'];
  $nombre = $registro ['NOM_PAC'];
  $apellido = $registro ['APE_PAC'];
  $edad = $registro['EDAD_PAC'];
  $direccion = $registro['DIR_PAC'];
  $telefono = $registro['TEL_PAC'];
  $celular = $registro['CEL_PAC'];
 }

else{
 echo "<script>alert('Paciente no encontrado en el sistema')</script>";
 }
}
if ($boton == "Buscar"){
 $sql1 = "select * from datosmedicos where CED_PAC = '$cedula'";
 $busqueda1 =mysql_query($sql1);

 if ($registro1=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda1)){
  $codigo = $registro1['COD_CONSULTA'];
  $altura = $registro1['ALT_PAC'];
  $peso = $registro1['PESO_PAC'];
  $fecha = $registro1['FECHA'];
  $tipconsulta = $registro1['TIPO_CONSULTA'];
  $sintomas = $registro1['SINTOMAS'];
  $observacion = $registro1['OBSERV'];
  $nhistoria = $registro1['HIS_PAC'];
  $cedula = $registro1['CED_PAC'];
  $medicamentos = $registro1['MEDI_PAC'];
  $operado = $registro1['OPERADO'];
  $alergias = $registro1['ALERGIAS'];

 }
}

if ($boton == "Modificar"){
 if ($cedula!=""){
 $sql="UPDATE datosmedicos SET ALT_PAC= '$altura', PESO_PAC='$peso', FECHA='$fecha', TIPO_CONSULTA='$tipconsulta', SINTOMAS='$sintomas', OBSERV='$observacion', HIS_PAC=$nhistoria, MEDI_PAC='$medicamentos', OPERADO='$operado', ALERGIAS='$alergias' where CED_PAC='$cedula'";
  mysql_query($sql);
  echo "<script>alert('Datos modificados correctamente')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.location='consulta.php'</script>";
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>alert('Para poder modificadar debe realizar una busqueda')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.location='consulta.php'</script>";
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<img src="imagenes/header.png">
 <h2>Historia médica</h2>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Cedula" name="CED_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $cedula; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Número de historia" name="HIS_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $nhistoria; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del paciente" name="NOM_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $nombre; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido del paciente" name="APE_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $apellido; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Edad" name="EDAD_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $edad; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Peso" name="PESO_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $peso; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Altura" name="ALT_PAC"  value="<?PHP echo $altura; ?>">
  <input type="date" placeholder="Fecha" name="FECHA"  value="<?PHP echo $fecha; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Codigo de consulta" name="COD_CONSULTA" class="input-100"  value="<?PHP echo $codigo; ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Tipo de consulta" name="TIPO_CONSULTA" class="text-center input-48" value="<?PHP echo $tipconsulta; ?>">
  <textarea name="SINTOMAS" class="input-100" placeholder="Sintomas" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $sintomas; ?></textarea>
  <textarea name="OBSERV" class="input-100" placeholder="Observaciones" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $observacion; ?></textarea>
   <textarea name="OPERADO" class="input-100" placeholder="Ha sido operado" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $operado; ?></textarea>
  <textarea name="ALERGIAS" class="input-100" placeholder="Sufre de alergias" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $alergias; ?></textarea>
  <textarea name="MEDI_PAC" class="input-100" placeholder="Medicamentos actuales" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $medicamentos; ?></textarea>

   <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Registrar" class="text-center inline-block col-md-3 btn-enviar espacio-arriba">
   <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Buscar" class="text-center inline-block col-md-3 btn-enviar espacio-arriba">
   <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Modificar" class="text-center inline-block col-md-3 btn-enviar espacio-arriba">
   <input type="button" value="Atras" class="text-center inline-block col-md-3 espacio-arriba btn-enviar" onclick = "location='menu.php'"/>


 </div>
 </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la historia medica no es una sola??? que va sufriendo cambios en el tiempo con fechas de cambios?

Comment: Si, la historia medica es una sola, pero el doctor me pide que necesita al menos ver la ultima consulta que el paciente tuvo para ver los medicamentos que le envio, los sintomas o todos los datos que el puso allí.

En su momento pense en hacerlo solo con un 'UPDATE' pero llegará algun punto en donde se quede sin caracteres.

Comment: ok, por favor limita la pregunta entonces solamente a la consulta. Y lo que no me queda claro es que tipo de solucion buscas. Lo que no te sale es el query sql?

Comment: Busco la manera de que se pueda guardar cada consulta (Cada vez que el paciente va) de manera independiente y luego yo pueda hacer esta busqueda para ver cuando fue la ultima vez que el paciente vino y me arroje los datos de esa ultima vez.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias primeramente cambiar el tipo de dato a tu campo FECHA por `DATETIME`,
luego para consultar fechas harias algo así: `WHERE FECHA >= '2017-01-22 15:31:00'`
Si quieres tambien podrias agregar un campo FECHAULTIMA o similar, con el Tipo de dato `DATETIME` y `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, campo que se actualizaria siempre en cada modificación de registro.

Ejemplo:

```
`FECHA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FECHAULTIMA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

De esta manera puedes acceder a la fecha de ultima modificación y FECHA podria ser usada para otra referencia que necesites como cuando se creó el registro, o simplemente usar este último.

Por favor no olvides de escapar tus datos para prevenir injeccion SQL con `mysqli_real_escape_string` (o [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)) y usando `mysqli` en vez de `mysql` que esta obsoleto.

Saludos